# Storing Keychain Keys in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, security, core-data, keychain

I'm using `CoreData` framework to store all the data for my iOS app. Some attributes contain sensitive data and need to be protected. Does it make sense to store the sensitive data in keychain and the keys to the data in `CoreData`? Is this secure or should I consider a different approach? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Keychain is designed to protect "secrets," which are small amounts of sensitive information that are generally used to access other things. This includes things like symmetric and private keys, access tokens, and passwords. To store larger amounts of sensitive information, you should encrypt it and store the keys in Keychain. You would store the encrypted data in Core Data, not the keys.